# reverse ssh tunneling: is there a 3rd machine between local and remote machines?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I'm facing for first time the need to connect my local pc (call it 'home') to my work pc (call it 'work') . Work pc CANNOT accept ssh connection because it's beside a firewall I cannot control.

I read that I could do something called "reverse ssh tunnelling". But it's not clear to me the number and the role of machines involved

Are involved 2 machines only? (home and work)
or do we need a 3rd machine (call it a vps) to estabilish bridge between home and work!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are involved 2 machines only? (home and work) or do we need a 3rd machine (call it a vps) to estabilish bridge between home and work!?

The answer to this question depends entirely on your particular situation. "Reverse ssh tunneling" means that you establish an ssh connection FROM your work machine TO your home machine, and then forward ports FROM your home machine TO your work machine over that connection.

If your work machine is able to connect directly to your home machine, then you don't need anything else. On your work machine, you can run something like:

```
ssh -R 2200:localhost:22 myhomeusername@my.home.machine
```

And as long as that connection is active, on your home machine you can connect to your work machine by running:

```
ssh -p 2200 myworkusername@localhost
```

---

If your work machine is *not* able to connect directly to your home machine, then you may need to arrange for some sort of intermediary, which would be a machine that (a) you can connect to from your work machine and (b) from which you can connect to your home machine.